# Error: Setting an Array Element with a Sequence. Keras Neural Network

Tags: python, arrays, keras, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I'm want to build DQNAgent but I have a problem whit the data or with the NN(I'm not sure).  I tried to solve it by changing the shape of the array but I'm always getting the same error:**ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.**

**This is the data:**

state(array,shape:(2,2)):

```
       [4499.74073719,  121.58564876],
       [4669.91329184,   42.37631835]])
  array([[-2000.        ,   290.01270128]])]
 [array([[-4370.,   800.],
       [ -635.,   800.]]) -12.0]]
```

Label(Q value):

```
array([0.23,1,3,0.1234])
```

The programe need to prodict the q_value baice on the data.
**This is the code:**

```
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dense(24,  activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(acton_size, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate))
    return model
```

```
    r_locs, i_locs, c_locs, ang, score=Game_step(random.randint(0,4))
    state=np.array([r_locs, i_locs, c_locs, ang])
    state=np.reshape(state,[2,2])
```

**ERROR:**

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Any idea how to solve this?
**THANKS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure about this, but it may be that the state matrix you are trying to process through the network is not being interpreted as you expect.  I believe, the network is expecting each sample to be a 2x2 matrix of numbers, and your state is a combination of numbers and arrays from what it appears.  This might point you in the right direction.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!, Appreciate it.